# Concatenate multiple node values when parsing XML

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm learning Python and need your help.

I'm trying to parse an XML file to TSV using minidom. In that XML file I have multiple tags with same name. I want concatenate them and return in a single delimited string. Can anyone help me.

XML:

```
<items>
<item_name>iPhone</item_name>
<category>Smart Phone</category>
<category>Electronics</category>
<category>Communications</category>
</items>
```

Desired output:

```
iPhone    Smart Phone, Electronics, Communications
```

Python Code:

```
dom = parseString(data)

xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('items')
for node in xmlTag:
    item = node.getElementsByTagName('item')[0]
    cat = node.getElementsByTagBane('category')
print("%s\t%s" % item, cat)
```

Comment: What is your problem? Also, I suppose you mispelled tagName for tagBane?

Comment: Is this your real code? There is a typo in `node.getElementsByTagBane()`. Furthermore, the selection of elements with tag name `'item'` will be empty because the xml you provided simply contains no element of that name. Please correct your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you the following code.
I don't know if I get your problem but your code seems incomplete.

```
dom = parseString(data)

xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('items')
for node in xmlTag:
    item = node.getElementsByTagName('item_name')[0]
    print item,
    cat = node.getElementsByTagBane('category')
    for s in cat:
        print s.childNodes[0].data,
    print ""
```